# Proof for The Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n^2-n}{4n^2+1}=\frac{3}{4},\space n\in\Bbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I am revising my knowledge on the topic of real analysis by attempting some simple proofs. The question requires for the proof of the Limit for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n^2-n}{4n^2+1}=\frac{3}{4}$ using the definition of convergence: $$\forall\epsilon>0\space\space\exists N\in\Bbb{R}\space s.t\space\space \forall n>N,|s_n-L|<\epsilon$$ Below is my working: $$|\frac{3n^2-n}{4n^2+1}-\frac{3}{4}|<\epsilon$$ $$|\frac{3n^2-n}{4n^2+1}-\frac{3n^2+\frac{3}{4}}{4n^2+1}|=|\frac{-n-\frac{3}{4}}{4n^2+1}|=\frac{|-n-\frac{3}{4}|}{4n^2+1}<\frac{4n}{4n^2}=\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon $$ $$\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon\rightarrow\frac{1}{\epsilon}<n$$ $$\forall n>N=\frac{1}{\epsilon},\space|\frac{3n^2-n}{4n^2+1}-\frac{3}{4}|<\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$$ By the definition of convergence,$\space\frac{3n^2-n}{4n^2+1}\rightarrow\frac{3}{4}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty.$

Is this correct? Any feedback would be greatly appeciated.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: how can you say $\frac{|-n-\frac{3}{4}|}{4n^2+1}<\frac{4n}{4n^2}$?

Comment: $4n>|-n-\frac{3}{4}|\space\forall n \in \Bbb{R}$  and  $4n^2<4n^2+1$ therefore $\frac{1}{4n^2+1}<\frac{1}{4n^2}$ so the statement holds

Comment: Triviality: in the third line you use $\to$ to mean "implies" which is always confusing in a limits question! And what you actually need to make the argument work is the converse of the one you write.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks, I understand that. Unfortunately I am still fairly new to stack exchange syntax and did not know how to type inline with the equation so I erroneously used $\rightarrow$ as I could not find a suitable alternative.

Comment: @AlexHughes take $n=0.1$ and calculate!! is it still $4n>|-n-\frac{3}{4}|$?

Comment: @ManjoyDas Sorry I should also have specified that since it is a sequence $n\in\Bbb{N}$

Comment: @AlexHughes that's the point...

Comment: @ManjoyDas all corrected :).

Comment: You may visit the [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site) designed for beginners in order to learn the syntax being used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need more words, and that as it stands the second line isn't quite right.

I would write

Given $\epsilon>0$ we want to find an $N$ such that for $n>N$ we have
$$|\frac{3n^2-n}{4n^2+1}-\frac{3}{4}|<\epsilon.\tag 1 $$

Let us see how big the left hand side can be:
$$|\frac{3n^2-n}{4n^2+1}-\frac{3n^2+\frac{3}{4}}{4n^2+1}|=|\frac{-n-\frac{3}{4}}{4n^2+1}|=\frac{|-n-\frac{3}{4}|}{4n^2+1}<\frac{4n}{4n^2}=\frac{1}{n},$$
so that (1) will be true for all $n>N:=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Check:**

With $n=\dfrac1{\epsilon}$,

$$\left|\frac{\dfrac3{\epsilon^2}-\dfrac1{\epsilon}}{\dfrac4{\epsilon^2}+1}-\frac{3}{4}\right|=\left|\frac{3-\epsilon}{4+\epsilon^2}-\frac{3}{4}\right|=\left|\frac{4+3\epsilon}{4(4+\epsilon^2)}\right|\epsilon<\left|\frac{4+3\epsilon}{16}\right|\epsilon<\epsilon.$$

Comment: Why does this prove the required inequality holds for all $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician: you are right, this is a partial check. Anyway, as the inequalities hold for all $\epsilon<4$, it will hold for all $\epsilon'<\epsilon$ and $n'>n$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon>0$ be any number.
Now
\begin{align}
&\left|\frac{3n^2-n}{4n^2+1}-\frac{3}{4}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{-4n-3}{4(4n^2+1)}\right|\\
&=\frac{4n+3}{4(4n^2+1)}\\
&<\frac{n+1}{(4n^2+1)}\\
&<\frac{n+1}{(n^2+1)}\\
&<\frac{n+1}{n^2}<\epsilon\quad &\text{whenever}\quad n^2\epsilon-n-1>0\\
&&\text{i.e whenever}\quad n>\dfrac{1+\sqrt {1+4\epsilon}}{2\epsilon}\\
\end{align}
Now you can take $N=\left[{\dfrac{1+\sqrt {1+4\epsilon}}{2\epsilon}}\right]+1$ and this also allows $N$ to be a positive integer rather than just a real number which, in cases, can be difficult to find out.
Therefore
$\left|\frac{3n^2-n}{4n^2+1}-\frac{3}{4}\right|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$

Comment: This answer would be better if you used $$\frac{n+1}{n^2} \le \frac{2n}{n^2} < \epsilon$$ provided that $n > \max\{1,2/\epsilon\}$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. yes that is good but also an extra condition is being applied to $n$. nevertheless thanks for your observation.

Comment: $n \ge 1$ is not a particularly stringent condition to place on a positive integer $n$.